# React Native Scrollview ref coming back undefined (mostly)

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am trying to make a button to scroll to the top of a scrollview in react native, but 9 times out of 10 the ref "scrollViewRef" comes back undefined. Occaisionally it works fine, which makes me think this is some kind of timing issue, its getting the reference before it has been created or something. setTimeout doesn't work. This is the case on IOS and Android. Cheers for reading!

Here is where i declare the scrollview and ref

```
   <ScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          ref={(ref) => {this.scrollViewRef = ref}}
          onScroll={({nativeEvent})=> { 
            if (this.isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
              this.increase()
            }
            this.props.onScroll();
          }}
          scrollEventThrottle={5}
   >
```

Here is where I try to scroll to top

```
  loadMoreButton = () => {

      if(this.state.lines >= 96 && Platform.OS != "web"){
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              if(this.scrollViewRef){
                this.scrollViewRef.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: 0, animated: false });
              }
            }}
          >
      ....
```

Comment: Can you show a print of the screen which has the ScrollView?

Comment: Hi, its 1000 lines of code long that screen :-/ so not really. Is there any bit in particular it would be handy to see?

Comment: OK so I think I fixed it. I had a booleon changing what was rendered, and on initial page load it had another scrollView rendering, and then it changed to this scroll view. Removed the other scrollview and it works OK.